# Java library for filtering user-entered content?

Tags: java, security, filtering

I am doing a Java-based web application. It allows users to enter content, which is displayed to other users.

Naturally for security reasons, I have to filter user content to prevent XSS and other attacks.

I understand that filtering user content is a much-discussed topic. I found many posts at SO, but they are related to theory discussion, PHP, ideas, etc. I need a Java library to use to avoid re-writing/inventing everything. I feel there must be one out there.

Is there such a library I can use?

Thanks for any info!

Comment: How about something like [this](http://code.google.com/p/owasp-java-html-sanitizer/).

Comment: Boris, could you please make a reply instead of comment? I have follow-up questions and would like to choose it as the answer.

Comment: I think the important thing is not to do formatting by string concatenation.

Comment: Don't know why there are people wanting to close this post. Can someone explain so that I can make better posts in the future?

Comment: @curios1 that's the restriction of SO - you may not ask for recommendations. Sounds not wise, I know ...

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp, thanks for your info. I understand that rule and did see many wild discussions for that type of questions. However, there are indeed a lot of good recommendations with specific advice that helps such as this one. It has to be decided on a case-by-case basis. Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sanitise user input to prevent XSS then [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) provide the standard implementation for doing that in their [AntiSamy](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_AntiSamy_Project) project.

There is a better implementation of this on google code called [owasp-java-html-sanitizer](http://code.google.com/p/owasp-java-html-sanitizer/), this allows you to define policies programmatically and then run the suspect HTML through the policy which will strip out all nonsense.

Here is an example from their website:

```
PolicyFactory policy = Sanitizers.FORMATTING.and(Sanitizers.LINKS);
String safeHTML = policy.sanitize(untrustedHTML);
```

This creates a policy that only allows formatting and links in the suspect HTML, everything else is removed.

Comment: This tool seems to meet my need. Have you ever used? Any experience to share with?

Comment: Yes, I use it in production. The only painful thing is deciding on the policy. I kept finding things that I wanted but that were stripped out because the policy was too tight (<table>, <a> etc...). I ended up just using their example [Ebay policy](http://code.google.com/p/owasp-java-html-sanitizer/source/browse/trunk/src/main/org/owasp/html/examples/EbayPolicyExample.java). Once you have that sorted it works really rather well.

Comment: Just a quick question. How does this package handle faulty html tags? Such as missing ending tags, incorrect nesting?

Comment: I believe it makes a best effort attempt to make valid HTML, it attempts to deduce what the user meant to write. Obviously there is only so much it can do if the HTML is really mangled...

Comment: Thanks so much for everything! Best.